# Window.open is not working in IE8 fine in firefox

Tags: gwt

I having trouble getting pop-up window in IE. I have used following code. Its works fine in Firefox but not in IE6.

```
Code:

com.google.gwt.user.client.Window.open(url, "Admin ",
                                   "menubar=no," + 
                                   "location=false," + 
                                   "resizable=yes," + 
                                   "scrollbars=yes," + 
                                   "status=no," + 
                                   "dependent=true");;


Any Help greatly Appreciated
```

Comment: check if your "url" variable value is correct URL format.

Answer (score 6):

It may be a little late, but IE (most versions) requires the second argument of window.open(URL, "window-name","") to have NO spaces, even though you put quotes around it:)

For example your code should change to "Admin_"

Comment: Correct answer :)  Changed spaces to underscores and it is working fine in IE8 now.